# Random forests, limitations concerning data distribution

Tags: random-forest

I analyse my data with Random Forests in R (package rfSRC). Variable selection is done by VSURF. The problem is very general, I think. Nevertheless I will ask my question with my data in mind.

In this certain case there are different sampling areas in floodplains along a river. Sampling points are not evenly distributed in all sampling areas. E.g. sampling site A was only sampled close to the river, while site B was sampled farther from the river as well. Distance to the river is included as an own variable and might mitigate the problem.

Is there a problem in using the area code as a variable and draw conclusions if certain sites show values that differ from other sites.

More general, my question could be: is it possible to predict conditions in variable ranges not measured but being in-between measured ranges? Is it a valid interpolation?